# How to change NTFS ACLs on linux?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, acl

It is not about samba configuration, I want to change Windows permissions on a external NTFS drive, or another partition in my PC whose runs Windows, or even a network directory (but my PC is not the server).

I want a icacls equivalent on linux, I found fatattr, but it only change some attributes, like hidden and system files, it is good, but still not what I am looking for.

I tried googling for "cacls alternative for linux" and "change ntfs acl linux" and "change windows permissions linux" and all other combinations you could imagine, but I just found about samba server configurations and setfacl that do not work on ntfs partitions.

Who could help me?

Comment: NTFS doesn't support linux ACL permissions, by the way... you have to use mount options to set permissions, as bodhi.zazen said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to do what you are asking.

You can use mount options to map users and set permissions, but I do not think you can changes the Windows parameters.

See the NTFS-3g documentation for details:

http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/

http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/#options

> Limitations
>
> The SIDs required to identify users and groups have to be built on Windows. A user mapping file can however be copied on any partition, even if it were never formatted or used by Windows.
>
> Some unusual basic rights configurations, where the group is denied rights granted to owner and to world (as in chmod 745,) are rejected by the Windows administration tools. They are however interpreted correctly by Windows itself. When using POSIX ACLs, more configurations are rejected by the Windows administration tools.
>
> The base version is best suited for dual-boot systems with several users, complex user configurations will take profit from POSIX ACLs. User mapping features required for devices which may be plugged into multiple Windows or Linux systems are not available yet.